# duplicity: how to prevent malicious user from messing with backups

Tags: security, backup, duplicity

I'm using duplicity on almost every host I'm maintaining for creating backups to a remote location (calling it "backup host").

How often and when to do full or incremental backups depends on the host and its use-case.

I'm not just trying to protect myself from typical failure (human error, hardware-/software, etc.), but also to recover from a potential attack.

In my cases I'm using the SSH/SFTP backend for running such duplicity backups.
Since duplicity needs read/write access to the backup host, somebody gaining control of the the to-be-backed-up hosts can also connect to the backup host and delete / mess with respective backups.

Despite that -- according to my understanding -- the to-be-backed-up hosts also /need/ to delete files on the backup host: In order not to run out of space, my to-be-backed-up hosts frequently call duplicity with `remove-all-but-n-full`- and `remove-all-inc-of-but-n-full`-actions in order to delete old backups.

Such cleanups, as far as I was told, can't happen on the backup host itself, due to the backups -- incl. duplicity's metadata regarding which files belong to which set -- being encrypted, whereas respective private key (GPG) is not present on the backup host.

So, to do such cleanups on the backup host, I'd have to do so based on file timestamps, which might result in corrupted/partial backup sets.

Currently, to "protect" myself from such an attack, I have a second backup host regularly connecting to the primary backup host which rsync's all backup data from the primary to the secondary backup host.

But here again I'm facing already above mentioned issues:

- I'm just copying files from the primary to the second backup host without any understanding of their structure (as in: I'll copy not yet completed files, partial sets, etc.).
- In order not to run out of space, I'll have to delete stale backups solely based on their file timestamps yet again, which might render backup sets unusable.

What is the most elegant and cleanest way for to-be-backed-up hosts being backuped, via duplicity, automatically, while ensuring an attacker gaining full access to the to-be-backed-up hosts can't mess with already created backups?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a good example of why "pushing" a backup is not as secure as "pulling" a backup.  Instead of running the backup job on the backup client and "pushing" the data to the backup server, run the job on the backup server, and "pull" the data from the client you want to back up.  This way, the client never has any login rights to the backup server.  That doesn't completely solve your problem, but it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: While that might be fair advice, I'm not aware of any solution similar to duplicity (regarding above mentioned features I use) doing it this way round.

Comment: If your chosen solution leads you into a bad security situation, consider whether it might be worthwhile to rethink your choice of backup solution. ZFS snapshots -- and its accompanying delegation of privileges that eliminate the need for root access -- is one possible alternative.

Comment: One technique you may be able to make use of is a restricted `ssh` key.  Create a private/public `ssh` key pair on the client that is to be backed up.  Install the public portion of that key on the backup storage server in `~root/.ssh/authorized_keys` along with a forced command (perhaps a script that you will need to craft for this purpose).  That key can then be used to log in to the storage server from the backup client with root privileges, but **only** for the purpose of running that specific script.  This would increase the difficulty of fully compromising your storage server.